# How to track multiple sites with Google Analytics in iOS if a singleton instance is running

Tags: ios, google-analytics, singleton, google-analytics-api

Using *Google Analytics* to track statistics of an iOS app. One of embedded libraries of the app is also using Google Analytics inside a singleton instance, so it cannot be used in conjunction with the singleton instance.

Google Analytics offers only one site tracking per `GANTracker` instance, so how can this app be configured to track multiple sites if it is explicitly noted as a *singleton*?

Comment: You can look at this answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347920/google-analytics-ios-sdk-multiple-accounts][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347920/google-analytics-ios-sdk-multiple-accounts