# Google Analytics iOS SDK - Multiple accounts

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-analytics

I am trying to make my view controllers be tracked by two different accounts on my iPhone app. I am currently using the version 1.5.1 of the SDK, which doesn't support this functionality. On the documentation of the version 2, it says that it supports multiple trackers, but I couldn't figure out a way to make both track the same view. Does anyone know how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the detailed explaination for the same

As of `version 2 of the SDK`, you can use multiple trackers in a single implementation, one per unique tracking ID. All trackers share the same global state held by your GAI singleton,including settings like periodic dispatch interval, app-level opt out, and debug mode.

Keep in mind that automatic screen tracking and uncaught exception tracking will only use one tracker to make tracking calls. If you are using these features and want to send similar data to other trackers, you will need to do so manually.

For reference, automatic screen tracking uses the tracker specified in the tracker property of a given `GAITrackedViewController`. Uncaught exception tracking uses the default tracker specified in your `GAI` instance.

[Here the detailed code & documenation about the same,you should view this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced)

I am sure this'll help you...!!!